# Reduce dependencies in angular js controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to reduce the dependencies that we give in angular js controllers like

`app.controller('sampleController', function($scope, $timeout, $localStorage, $http, $location))
.controller('sample1Controller', function($scope, $timeout, $localStorage, $http, $location))
.controller('sample2Controller', function($scope, $timeout, $localStorage, $http, $location))
.controller('sample3Controller', function($scope, $timeout, $localStorage, $http, $location))`

and I'm using the same set of dependencies for multiple controllers.

Can we store all the dependencies in a variable use that to all the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

try to create services for the functionality in the controllers.  then your code will be like this, for example,

```
    app.controller('sampleController', function($scope, serviceA, $location))

app.service('serviceA', function($timeout, $localStorage, $http) {
// do something here
});
```

the more you abstract code out of your controllers, less your injections will be

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom service in angular which returns the dependencies and you can inject that service in your controller and access them. but you will not be able to include $scope in the service as scope is available only for controller.

```js
// angular module implementation
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  angular
    .module('app',[]);
    
})();

// angular controller
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  var controllerId = 'myCtrl';
  
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller(controllerId,['common',function(common){
        var vm = this;
        
        init();
        
        function init(){
          vm.count = 0;
          
          common.interval(function(){
            vm.count++;
            
          }, 1000);
        }
      
    }]);
    
})();

// service that returns the depandancies
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  var serviceId = 'common';
  
  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory(serviceId, ['$timeout','$interval', function($timeout,$interval){
      
        return {
          timeout: $timeout,
          interval: $interval
        };
      
    }]);
    
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='myCtrl as vm'>
    <h1>My Count is: {{vm.count}}!</h1>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

To eliminate $scope from your controller go ahead mvvm approach. http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see all the dependencies statically injected to your controllers and need to do it in a single place, you can use $injector to create an object which will give reference to all your dependencies.

```
.factory('dependencies', function($injector){

   var dependencies;
   dependencies.fooDependency = $injector.get('fooDependency');
   dependencies.barDependency = $injector.get('barDependency');

   return dependencies;
})
```

Inject this factory to your controller and use it to access your dependencies.